# Linq to Entities - OrderBy Tags (many to many relationship)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

asp.net mvc 4, Entity Framework 5, SQL Server 2012 Express, Code First

I have a Place model:

```
public virtual int PlaceID { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

and a related Tag model:

```
public virtual int TagID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual string NamePlural { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

they have a many to many relationship.

I am selecting all places with the tag 'Restaurant':

```
 List<Place> Restaurants = allPlaces.Where(
    p => p.Tags.Any(
       t => t.Name == "Restaurant")).OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

I would like to display this by ordered tag - then sorted by name.

Lets say there are 5 Places:

```
My Cafe Bar, Tags="Restaurant", "Cafe", "Bar"
Another Cafe, Tags="Restaurant", "Cafe"
Marios Italian, Tags="Restaurant", "Italian", "Bar"
Donnies Pizzaria, Tags="Restaurant", "Italian"
A1 Chinese, Tags="Restaurant", "Chinese"
Fusion One, Tags="Restaurant", "Chinese", "Italian"
China Garden, Tags="Restaurant", "Chinese"
```

I would like to output in the below order (as they're all Restaurants there's no need to output a Restaurants group):

```
>>Bars
Marios Italian
My Cafe Bar

>>Cafes
Another Cafe
My Cafe Bar

>>Chinese
A1 Chinese
Fusion One
China Garden

>>Italian
Donnies Pizzaria
Fusion One
Marios Pizzaria
```

In my view I would like to display them as above - with headings.

Is this possible with Linq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a `GroupBy`, not `OrderBy`. Check this query:

```
var restaurants = allPlaces.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == "Restaurant"))
                           .SelectMany(p => p.Tags, (p, t) => new { Tag = t.Name, Name = p.Name })
                           .GroupBy(i => i.Tag)
                           .Where(g => g.Key != "Restaurant")
                           .Select(g => new { Tag = g.Key, Places = g })
                           .ToList();
```

It will result a list of anonymous objects with two properties:

```cs
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public List<string> Places { get; set;}
}
```

I'm pretty sure about the logic here, but not about LINQ to Entities support for all things used there.

Comment: Thanks. The compiler doesn't like the 'new' in the second line.

Comment: Updated my answer, check now, please.

Comment: Looks like you were right :) LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType5`2[System.String,System.String]] ToList[<>f__AnonymousType5`2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType5`2[System.String,System.String]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Thanks; that's fixed some issues. Looking at this in more depth - I actually need other properties available. For example - there is a URL property associated with every place that I need. How easy would it be to return place & tag objects? Alternatively just adding a URL property to the anonymous object would work...

Comment: actually I guess I can just add to the Name = p.Name list.. I would like to put this in a non-anonymous object - how can I do that?

Comment: Still interested in how to create a model based on your original Linq - however what I ended up doing was creating a flat dataset - like this (TagAndPlaces object just contains 3 strings):          
restaurants = db.Places
.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == "Going Out"))
.SelectMany(p => p.Tags, (p, t) =>
new TagAndPlaces { Tag = t.Name, Name = p.Name, URL = p.URL })
.OrderBy(t => t.Tag)
.Where(p => p.Tag != "Restaurant" && p.Tag != "Going Out" && p.Tag != "Shopping" && p.Tag != "More")
.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looking at this a different way.

I simply pass all *tags* to the view (alphabetically sorted) - then loop through those. Whilst looping through each tag, I loop through each place within it (navigation property).

Very simple solution to the problem:

```
@foreach (var t in Model)
{
   <h2>@t.Name</h2>

   foreach (var p in t.Places)
   {
       <li>@Html.ActionLink(p.Name, "Details", new { URL = p.URL })</li>
   }
}
```

Comment: this actually proved to be flawed because the navigation property returned *every* place, not just the correctly tagged ones.

See answer above for a modified version of what I did in the end.